# Automation testing on safari on windows 7

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, safari, automation

I have automation script (selenium webdriver, java)running on ff, chrome and IE but need to run them on safari, as I have windows 7 I am not sure can I download safari and run automation on that. If anyone faced same issue or someone know the sollotion pls guide me through the process

Comment: FWIW: Safari hasn't been supported on Windows since 2012.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be highly recommended to use Browserstack, Saucelabs or testingbot cloud services.

A similar question is posted [here](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/18494/what-is-the-procedure-to-start-safari-browser).